# Change webjob from on demand to schedule

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have an azure webjob that was deployed as on demand. Is there a way to change this to run on a schedule without redeploying?
Not a lot of info out there on this.

I tried creating a new schedule collection like [this](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html) and adding a job to run the existing webjob, but that didn't seem to work either.

I prefer to do this in the GUI portal, but if its not possible, I'll do it in powershell (if it is possible like that).

(Also, if it can **only** be changed by redeploying, I need to know that and it effectively answers the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the link in the original post I referenced worked. The thing that was missing for me was the understanding that creating a trigger job in scheduler will not affect the run status (on-demand or scheduled) of the web job itself. In my case it stayed "on-demand", but the schedule was in fact running it.

Answer (score 6):

To easily add a schedule to your triggered (on demand) webjob add a file called `settings.job` at the root of your webjob with this content:

`{"schedule": "the schedule as a cron expression"}`

Find out more about this [here](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs)

> Note: it'll only work properly for Standard or Premium sites and requires you to set the site as always on.

Comment: I was trying not to redeploy. I can easily modify the deployment, but I was trying to modify while already in Azure.

Comment: There is no need to redeploy, just go to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole you'll find a file browser there where you can add the file. easy peasy.

Comment: Side note: Just ran it on a Basic site and it's also working.

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the direction on how to do this via PowerShell.  It looks possible to add already existing WebJobs to a scheduler.
[Create a Scheduled Azure WebJob with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307232/create-a-scheduled-azure-webjob-with-powershell)