# Error in creating azure webjob through powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I created an azure webjob through powershell with the following commands by following this link [Create a Scheduled Azure WebJob with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307232/create-a-scheduled-azure-webjob-with-powershell)

Webjob got successfully created in the mentioned webapp, but when I try to start the web job the following exception is thrown

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurredMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. System.Net.WebException:
>   The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
>
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode
>   expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal,
>   StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)

I access a storage account inside the webjob, It runs fine when I deploy through visual studio problem occurs only when using Powershell cmdlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storage account that web job accesses is in different subscription to that it is hosted hence the error 403, I changed the subscription of storage account to the same of web job and it works fine.